# What are the units of the accuracy_radius field in MaxMind DB?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

This field was added to the database in April 2016, but the release notes give no indication about what the units are.

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/release-notes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The radius in kilometers around the specified location where the IP
>   address is likely to be.

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/